# I can't run on my project Karma and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I follow the book AngularJS: Up and Running and at the chapter where the author said to use Karma and Jasmine for testing, he didn't said too many words how to organize your project and where exactly to install Karma and Jasmine.

I installed nodejs and runs well. Then I put in xampp/htdocs/angularjs-up-and-running my project with the file to test.

In the same folder I have none_modules. In this last folder I have karma, karma-jasmine and karma-chrome-launcher.

From the console I go in the c:/xampp/htdocs/angularjs-up-and-running/none_modules/karma folder and I used the command:

```
karma init
```

I answered to all questions then I used then:

```
karma start
```

Chrome is opening like this:
[image: Chrome Debug]

but I don't know how to test my js file. I tried to put http://localhost:9876/controller.js to test my file but I got this on my Console:

[image: Console Image]

Controller.js

```
angular.module('notesApp', []).controller('ListCtrl', [ function(){
var self = this;
self.items = [
    {id: 1, label: 'First', done: true},
    {id: 2, label: 'Second', done: false}
];

self.getDoneClass = function(item) {
    return {
        finished: item.done,
        unfinished: !item.done
    };
};
```

}]);

I'm new to angularjs and this king of testing. I searched on the interned for solutions but my problem is that I don't know how to use my file controller.js to test it, and I didn't find a solution.
Please someone give a hand in this situation.

Comment: You need to write spec files and specify them in Karma config. No need to do anything in Chrome window.

Comment: Do you mean to to change here: `module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: 'angularjs-up-and-running',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [controller.js
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],
`

Comment: Yes, include spec files there, like that http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a file called [karma.conf.js](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html). In this file, you specify a 'files' parameter with an array of files that contain the tests that you want to run. So you would write a test called 'app/mytest.js' and in your karma.conf.js file, you would put the path to that test.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
    files: [
        "app/test.js",
    ],   
});
};
```

Note that you need to include your angular module and controller dependencies in the test file itself.

So contents of app/mytest.js might look like (from the [angular documentation:](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing))

```
describe('PasswordController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.grade', function() {
    it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
      $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I get this error, after I did what u said:`ReferenceError: test is not defined`

Comment: This isn't meant to be a step-by-step solution, rather a guideline to setting up your tests. If you want an exact answer, post a link to a gist or your github repo.

Comment: I though that if you use Karma and Jasmine you got into those error too. I solved that error and now I get  ` Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`. Thank for trying to help me.

Comment: Yes, sorry if it's not clear, you do need to define the path to angular and all dependencies in the karma.conf.js files array.

Comment: No errors now in the console, but I don't get anything in console: **16 11 2016 17:44:48.624:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/**  **16 11 2016 17:44:48.638:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome**  **Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.004 secs / 0 secs)**

Comment: I add it in the question, above, were is Controller.js

Comment: Finally I understand. If there is no error nothing will display :)). Thank you @Larry Turtis.